# Creating a UI similar to Apple's Reminders app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making an application which would benefit from a layout similar to Apple's Reminders app.

My best guess is that each reminder group has its own table view, the coloured name of which is the header. The tableview does not seem to be populated until the group is selected. - Perhaps each table is displayed  using a custom modal presentation segue?

The groups themselves can be scrolled and act as if they are also a tableView.

Any ideas on how this has been achieved and if there are any demo apps with similar functionality?

[image]

Comment: `UICollectionView` with custom layout would be a better approach.

Comment: Here is a repo that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController